# pySerial wait for "#" character to print output from USB serial device

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyserial

I'm writing a python script that connects to a USB serial device. Whenever a command is sent and executed, the PIC returns with a hashtag. Ie. "Command executed successfully. \n# "

I'd like my python script to wait for the hashtag before outputting the data. How can I do this?
Here's what I have. It doesn't seem to actually print the text received from the PIC. Any help is appreciated

```
if port.isOpen():    
    try:
        for x in range(0,100):
            time.sleep(0.05)
            port.write("command 1" + "\r\n")
            numLines = 0
            // wait for "#" to print output
            while True:
                response = port.readline()
                if "#" in response:
                    print(response)
                    numLines = numLines + 1
                if(numLines >= 1):
                    break

            time.sleep(0.05)
            port.write("command 2" + "\r\n")
            numLines = 0
            // wait for "#" to print output
            while True:
                response = port.readline()
                if "#" in response:
                    print(response)
                    numLines = numLines + 1
                if(numLines >= 1):
                    break

            time.sleep(0.05)
            port.write("command 3" + "\r\n")
            numLines = 0
            // wait for "#" to print output
            while True:
                response = port.readline()
                if "#" in response:
                    print(response)
                    numLines = numLines + 1
                if(numLines >= 1):
                    break

    except Exception, e1:
        print("An error occured: " + str(e1))
    port.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`port.readline()` will read the serial port till it receives a `\n`. So, the response will contain the string "Command executed successfully. \n". Since there is no "#" in this string, again the code will encounter the `port.readline()` statement. This time it will read "#" but since there is no "\n", the code will be stuck there resulting in an infinite loop.

Pyserial provides a method called `read():`

> `read(size=1)`
>
> Parameters:   size – Number of bytes to read. Returns:    Bytes read from
>   the port. Return type:    bytes Read size bytes from the serial port. If
>   a timeout is set it may return less characters as requested. With no
>   timeout it will block until the requested number of bytes is read.

read() provides a parameter size (with default =1) which specifies the number of bytes to be read. So, you can specify the number of bytes in the string sent by the PIC as a parameter. You can also use the following alternative:

```
// wait for "#" to print output
while True:
    response += port.read()
    if "#" in response:
        print(response)
        numLines = numLines + 1
    if(numLines >= 1):
         break
```

Comment: `response += port.read()` can potentially grow very large if '#' arrives very late.  A better approach is like: `target = '#'; response = (response + port.read())[-len(target):]` to keep the accumulated string no longer that the target string, whatever size that may be, followed by `if target == response`.

Answer (score 0):

If you send some white space to the device, as if it were a terminal command, it will prod it into a response with your "#" in it.  I have been successfully using that method.  Specifically I send a single space " " plus the terminal line ending (i.e. "\n" or "\r\n" depending on the device).